# My array won't print? (Java using Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to work on an assignment. We're supposed to create a deck of 36 cards. 
These cards will be from 1-9 and will appear 4 times. 
I figured out the simple for loop for this, but when i try and see if it worked by throwing it into a system print it doesn't work??

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;

public class FinalProgram {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] deck = new int[36];
        int arraySize;
        arraySize = deck.length ;

    }           

    public static void initDeck(int deck[], int arraySize){

        int j = 1;
        for (int i=0; i < arraySize ; i++){

            deck[i] = j;
            j++;

            if(j==10){
                j=1;
            }
            System.out.print(deck); 
        }
    }    
}
```

Wow, I am asking a question about something I didn't understand. Down votes are really unnecessary ):
I know this might seem like a stupid question but I am not very familiar with the rules of java. 
Believe it or not, one answer helps a lot.

Comment: Why would your program print anything?

Comment: `initDeck` is never called?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't have it in a method at first and it still didn't print D:

Comment: When I remove the method and leave it in main I get this: [I@22998b08

Comment: You cant print an array directly, 

`System.out.print(deck[i]);` would be correct inside the for loop

Comment: @izzystreaks That's the default `toString()` for arrays in Java.  If you want it to be pretty, use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(someArray));`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to call your function in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] deck = new int[36];
    int arraySize;
    arraySize = deck.length ;
    initDec(deck, arraySize); // add this
}
```

Also, when you print an array you need to use

```
System.out.print(Arrays.toString(deck));
```

Otherwise you print the address

Comment: I do not think such answer will help anybody at all specially the op who is novice

Comment: if you explain how to call a function in main method I gladly remove my down vote. **your answer needs to be more informative**

Comment: Ok, Thanks, I used the arrays.tostring and it worked. 
Im sorry for being such a noob. / //

Comment: no worries, I know how to call the method in main. (:

Comment: Glad it helped! Also, you shouldnt need to pass the arraySize as a parameter. Just call `deck.length` in your `initDeck` method to get the size

Comment: yeah i know!! these are old habits from coding in visual basic (which was an amazingly easy language)

Comment: @KickButtowski it seems like it was of help to the op. Also, could you kindly remove your down vote or be more specific in what your opinion is of a "good" answer.

Comment: @bcorso first, the op just looked for a copy paste situation. in order to be helpful for other who may see your answer, please explain how to call a method in a main and how Arrays.toString works and I gladly remove my downvote. **make your answer more informative for other who wants to learn**

Comment: @KickButtowski Sorry, the OP is not asking how Arrays.toString works. I'm sure there are plenty of SO questions on "how do Arrays.toString" if the OP wants to follow up on that.

Comment: @bcorso put something why are you haggling with me? :'(